# how to make a windows forms app unresizable?

Tags: vb.net

how to make the windows app in vs 2008 unresizable?because when you launch the application and  point and drag to its corners, the window grows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the `FormBorderStyle` to a fixed one, depends what look you want. [Here's a full list of options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41(VS.71).aspx), you probably want `Fixed3D` or `FixedSingle`

You also probably want to set [`MaximizeBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.maximizebox.aspx) to false.

Both of these can be found in the designer as options on the form, or set in code, whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on the properties of the window control in the properties window. You'll probably figure out how to do this + how to control few more staff about the window..

Answer (score 1):

Change the [ResizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.resizemode.aspx) property of the window.